# Laravel 5 get row from relationship model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have the following relationship models setup:

- User
- Users can have many job titles
- Users can have many employee types

  ```
  <?php

  namespace App\Models\User;

  use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
  use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
  use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
  use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
  use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;

  class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract
  {
      use Authenticatable, CanResetPassword;

      /**
       * The database table used by the model.
       *
       * @var string
       */
      protected $table = 'user';

      /**
       * The attributes that are mass assignable.
       *
       * @var array
       */
      protected $fillable = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'status', 'activation_code'];

      /**
       * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
       *
       * @var array
       */
      protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token', 'activation_code'];

      /**
       * The roles that belong to the user.
       *
       * @return Object
       */
      public function roles()
      {
          return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\User\Role')->withTimestamps();
      }

      /**
       * The employee types that belong to the user.
       *
       * @return Object
       */
      public function employeeTypes()
      {
          return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\User\EmployeeType')->withTimestamps();
      }

      /**
       * The job itles that belong to the user.
       *
       * @return Object
       */
      public function jobTitles()
      {
          return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\User\JobTitle')->withTimestamps();
      }
  }
  ```

Now, I want to be able to select the a list of users and all their job titles and employee types.

I have tried something like this with no such luck!  Please could someone advise how this is possible?

```
$this->user->whereIn('id', $ids)->jobTitles()->get();
```

The above code gives the error:

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::jobTitles()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [eager loading](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading):

```
$this->user->whereIn('id', $ids)->with('jobTitles', 'employeeTypes')->get();
```

You can only call relationships directly from a model, that's why your attempt failed (`whereIn()` returns `Builder`).

Eager/nested loading is very efficient way to fetch data before looping through multiple models and their relations (otherwise you may end up having A LOT of db queries) ;)